# Trouble creating certificate in AWS ACM via Cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-acm

I am trying to understand how certificates are managed in AWS ACM. My end goal is to deploy a service using https and I need to do it all via IaC, and I am using Cloudformation.

I already ran a previous CF stack to create the hosted zone and everything I need.

Now I am trying to run a CF stack to create the certificate itself. I have matched the hostedzoneID with the certificate, the hostedzone has a CNAME record for the certificate validation `_somethingblablablaf4fb148188e5.dfgdfgsmznr.acm-validations.aws.`

The stack runs OK and the certificate is being created in ACM. The validation chosen in the CF template is explicitely DNS.

Yet, the certificate is stuck in pending validation all the time and expires after 72 hours.

I read AWS docs and I have done everything as they ask as far as I know. I am not sure what is going wrong here.

Would anyone have any idea?

My CF template:

```
Parameters:
  DomainName:
    Type: String
    Description: The name of the domain you want to register.
  wagWorldHostedZone:
    Type: String
    Description: The hostedZoneID of the Hosted Zone you previously created.

Resources:
  wagWorldCertificate:
    Type: AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate
    Properties:
      DomainName: !Ref DomainName
      ValidationMethod: DNS
      DomainValidationOptions:
        - DomainName: !Ref DomainName
          HostedZoneId: !Ref wagWorldHostedZone
```

Comment: You say you created the hosted zone, but is it for a domain that you actually own? Did you configure the settings at your domain registrar to use the DNS name servers provided by your Route53 hosted zone? A Route53 hosted zone doesn't actually "work" until you actually have it connected to your domain registrar. And until you have that working properly, your ACM DNS validation will not complete.

Comment: thanks very much for that light bulb moment! This was indeed tie right solution. I wish Amazon would be a tad more helpful with their guidance..anyways, thanks very much to you! How do I accept your reply as the answer to my problem so you get your points? I don't see the normal green tick to accept. Perhaps I need to wait a day or 2 before I can do that...I'll see. Thanks again! :)

Comment: I posted it as a comment, not an answer, because I was asking a clarifying question about your issue. I just posted an answer if you want to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure your domain registrar to use the Route53 hosted zone's name servers. Until you do that the DNS records in your hosted zone aren't actually going to work. You have to have your domain actually resolving to the Route53 hosted zone before you can do the ACM DNS validation.